# is there an IDE or text editor for the mac that understands the module pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, editor

Neither NetBeans, nor Eclipse do very well with parsing the module pattern and putting the code into their outliners in a useful way. Is there something that does it better these days?

Answer (score 2):

Just found out how to make eclipse use the aptana plug-in for editing those files. That's better....

1. install [aptana](http://aptana.org/)
2. preferences > general > editors > file associations
3. select aptana in lower pane
4. click Default

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724234/prefered-javascript-editor-for-mac) has some good answers, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Generally all IDEs from [JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/) has very good support for navigating and refactoring complex JavaScript constructs (including prototypical inheritance and the module pattern). I am particular impressed with their ability to refactor across HTML, CSS and JavaScript

You can read more about their JavaScript support [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/editors/javascript_editor.jsp?ide=idea). Also note that this extensive JavaScript support is available across their entire line of [Ruby](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/), [Python](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), [Java](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), [PHP](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) and [Web](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Eclipse (Kepler) understands and outlines modules